# Dropdown-List - Multi-Selection should add text to Textbox in several Lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

**Hello everybody! :)**

I've made an easy random Drop-Down-list on our "Price-Request-Site" with all the Items in the List that we sell to our Customers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQEgN.jpg
And because they need to request Prices for those items, they can select one or more items from the Dropdown-List and the Output goes to a "simple Textbox"

You have to Select one or more Items from that DropDown-list and the JavaScript should "paste" the selected List-items to the Textbox.
The Textbox is already a part of a "Formular" to send the Textbox-input as an E-mail.

**My JavaScript does the following at the moment:**

If click an Item from the List, the Item-name appears in the Text-box in the first Line.
If I click a Second OR/AND another item, the JavaScript will overwrite the now existing "Item/Textline" from the first Line in the Textbox.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMx2P.jpg"
**I need the following solution to my JavaScript and it should be easy as possible:**

When I click to another Item from the List, it should be added to the Second Line, When I click another Item, it should be added in the next (3rd) Line...

**Background-information:**

This Script should make it easier for the Customer to write a Price-Request-EMail to us. 
(Without searching through the Shop and looking for or Article-Numbers, instead he can choose Products from the Dropdown-list with an Output to this Email-form/textbox)

```
function favsports()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("mylist");
document.getElementById("favorite").value=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

**I would be very Happy if someone could help me with my issue, i'am really new to JS :D**